# First Time SoundJS User, Can't Seem To Get A Sound To Play

Tags: javascript, createjs, soundjs

I'm just... trying to get SoundJS to play a sound. It appears that the file never load as my handleLoad function is never called. Any ideas?

```
    var audioPath = "snd/";
    var sounds = [
        { id: "mySound", src: "gaia.mp3" }
    ];

    function init( ) {
        createjs.Sound.addEventListener( "fileload", handleLoad );
        createjs.Sound.registerSounds( sounds, audioPath );
    }

    function handleLoad( event ) {
        console.log( "Hello from handleLoad" );
    }
```

I get a "creates.Sound.registerSounds is not a function" error when init runs.

Comment: If you've pasted the error message exactly as it was presented, then the problem is that your program has a typo.  The name of the function shown in the error message has `creates` where it should have `createjs`.  But the name is correct in the sample code.  Did you paste the code sample, or did you retype it?

Comment: I retyped it, I typo'd missing the "j". :( Really good thought though.

This is the complete error copied from the console:
TypeError: createjs.Sound.registerSounds is not a function. (In 'createjs.Sound.registerSounds( sounds, audioPath )', 'createjs.Sound.registerSounds' is undefined)

Comment: Ah, in that case it must be the other typo :-)  According to https://createjs.com/getting-started/soundjs the name of the function you want is `createjs.Sound.registerSound`, not `registerSounds` with a final `s`.

Comment: @ottomeister - There are both `registerSound` and `registerSounds` APIs. One takes a single item, the other takes an array. https://createjs.com/docs/soundjs/classes/Sound.html#method_registerSounds

Answer (score 0):

Your demo should work.

I copied your code into a JSFiddle, and pointed it at a sound that I know exists.https://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/vj8rLghb/

The only difference is I added the 3rd parameter because it is being loaded cross-domain

```
createjs.Sound.addEventListener("fileload", handleLoad, true);
```

Additionally, changes in Chrome mean that audio can't play without a user interaction, so once the audio is loaded, I added a document-click listener so it plays when you click the page anywhere.

Can you post the full error you get in the console? It is unclear if `registerSounds` is undefined, or if it doesn't exists on `undefined`, which indicates that `createjs.Sound` is undefined. Have you ensured that SoundJS is included properly? Try putting this in the console:

```
console.log(createjs.Sound);
```

Hope that helps!